# Call a WCF Operation from Windows Service WCF Host

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, service

I am new to WCF programming.
Here's what I need:

1. A Windows service that hosts a WCF Service. (Done)
2. A client application that can call WCF Service operations such as GetValue() from the running Windows service (Done)
3. The Windows service needs to call the operation Start() from the WCF service when the Windows service starts. The application in (2) could not retrieve data without the Windows service calling Start() operation first. (Not done)

The Windows service needs to start once the PC starts. Then it should begin logging some data. The user can run the client application anytime to retrieve logged data.

However, I could not do the automated logging part because the client is the one who invokes the constructor of the WCF Service. This cannot be done inside the windows service's OnStart() method.

Is there a way to invoke a WCF operation from the Onstart() method of Windows service?

Answer (score 0):

As - if you didn't configure it otherwise - a new instance of the WCF service class is created upon every call from the client, you could yourself also create a new instance of the class and just call your method. From your service's point of view, it is just a normal class.

It would help greatly if you could elaborate on what's done in `Start`.

Comment: I don't think I understand. I thought if I create an instance of WCF service, 2 different clients would access that same instance.

Comment: No. It is not even guaranteed that the same client will access the same instance when performing two different function calls. You *can* configure WCF to act like this (sessions/singleton pattern), but by default this is not the case.

Comment: Ok, I tried it with different clients, and you're right. Maybe I'm not using WCF for its purpose. I need to run different client applications to access the same data from the service.

Comment: If it's not guaranteed to access the same instance, then WCF is only good for helper functions? Not for live objects? Maybe I should use TCPListener and TCPClient instead to achieve my objectives?

Comment: Ok, sorry I configured it to be a singleton. It looks like it's working as expected, and the service constructor was called when the service host was also created. I'll try to see more if this has solved my problem. Thanks.